# How to fix Internal Server Error in Laravel 5.8 Ajax Form Submit

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, internal-server-error

I am working on form submission in Laravel using Ajax but it hangs, checking console.log I get Internal Server Error 500

I am using Laravel 5.8, the csrf token are included at the meta name and also in the ajax function, using console.log all values including _token appear in the console

This is the form controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator,Redirect,Response;
use App\Contact;

class FormController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('ajax-form');
    }       

    public function store(Request $request)
    {  
        request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'mobile_number' => 'required|unique:users'
        ]);

        $data = $request->all();
        $check = Contact::insert($data);
        $arr = array('msg' => 'Something goes to wrong. Please try again lator', 'status' => false);
        if($check){ 
        $arr = array('msg' => 'Successfully submit form using ajax', 'status' => true);
        }
        return Response()->json($arr);

    }
}
```

This is my blade file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <title>Laravel 5.7 </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" />
  <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }} "></script>  
  <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.validate.js') }}"></script>  
  <script src="{{ asset('js/additional-methods.min.js') }}"></script>
  <style>
   .error{ color:red; } 
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2 style="margin-top: 10px;">Laravel 5.7 Ajax Form Submission Example - <a href="https://www.tutsmake.com" target="_blank">TutsMake</a></h2>
    <br>
    <br>

    {{-- <form id="contact_us" method="post" action="{{ route('name') }}"> --}}
    <form id="contact_us" method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">
      @csrf
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Please enter name">
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email Id</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Please enter email id">
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
      </div>      
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mobile_number">Mobile Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile_number" class="form-control" id="mobile_number" placeholder="Please enter mobile number" maxlength="10">
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('mobile_number') }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success d-none" id="msg_div">
              <span id="res_message"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" id="send_form" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>

</div>
<script>
   if ($("#contact_us").length > 0) {
    $("#contact_us").validate({

    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        maxlength: 50
      },

       mobile_number: {
            required: true,
            digits:true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength:12,
        },
        email: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 50,
                email: true,
            },    
    },
    messages: {

      name: {
        required: "Please enter name",
        maxlength: "Your last name maxlength should be 50 characters long."
      },
      mobile_number: {
        required: "Please enter contact number",
        minlength: "The contact number should be 10 digits",
        digits: "Please enter only numbers",
        maxlength: "The contact number should be 12 digits",
      },
      email: {
          required: "Please enter valid email",
          email: "Please enter valid email",
          maxlength: "The email name should less than or equal to 50 characters",
        },

    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
     $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
      });
      $('#send_form').html('Sending..');
      console.log($('#contact_us').serialize());
      $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url('save-form')}}",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#contact_us').serialize(),
        success: function( response ) {
            $('#send_form').html('Submit');
            $('#res_message').show();
            $('#res_message').html(response.msg);
            $('#msg_div').removeClass('d-none');

            document.getElementById("contact_us").reset(); 
            setTimeout(function(){
            $('#res_message').hide();
            $('#msg_div').hide();
            },1000);
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My route

```
 Route::post('save-form', 'FormController@store');
```

I need the form to submit to the database.

Comment: [status 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. You have to look in `storage/logs/laravel.log` to know what's happening

Answer (score 0):

What is this `use Validator,Redirect,Response;`?

Use laravel helper function: `response()->json($arr);` or just `return $arr;`

Comment: Thanks @Alexis Navarro, I have put the Validators, Redirect and Response on separate lines. and I use response()->json($arr); in my controller, I still get same error,

Comment: Remove those use statements, what do they do? Use laravel helper functions or read the documentation on facades because those are not the correct namespaces.